# symfony 1.2 forms renderRow error message problem

Tags: forms, symfony1

Im trying to render a row field in a template with some extra styles, like this:

```
<?php echo $form['email']->renderRow(array('class' => 'text')) ?>    
<?php echo $form['email']->renderError() ?>
```

The problem occurs when my form doesnt validate on this field... then it displays the error message 2 times!, i.e the renderRow renders one errorMsg string, and the renderError does it again... How can i stop renderRow from displaying the error message?

If I just do this, then it works:

```
<?php echo $form['email']  ?>
```

But in that case I cant style the field as I want....

thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am pretty sure this is also valid for 1.2.  Instead of using renderRow, use something like this:

```
<?php echo $form['FormElementName']->renderLabel() ?> //display form element label
<?php echo $form['FormElementName']->renderError() ?> //display form element error (if exist)
<?php echo $form['FormElementName']->render(array('class' => 'text')); ?>  //display form element
```

renderRow does them all at once.

**EDIT** *From comments (Flask) - added ->render(array('class' => 'text'));*

Comment: Thanks! But how can I add a style to the my form component?

Comment: You can specify HTML attributes on your widget.  In this manner, you could specify a HTML 'class' attribute, and then use this in your CSS to apply a style.  More information can be found here:  http://www.symfony-project.org/forms/1_2/en/01-Form-Creation#chapter_01_sub_the_widgets_html_attributes

Comment: use `<?php echo $form['FormElementName']->render(array('class' => 'text')); ?>` instead of `<?php echo $form['FormElementName'] ?>`